# Draw a rectangle with PHP at an angle

Tags: php, gd, draw

I would like to draw a rectangle at an angle with PHP. I know that you can draw rectangles with PHP using `imagefilledrectangle` but how to draw it an an angle.

```
public function drawshelf($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $width, $angle = 'false'){
    imagesetthickness ( $this->canvas, 1 );
    for ($i=0; $i < $width; $i++){ //HORIZONTAL
        imageline( $this->canvas, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $this->color );
        $y1++; $y2++;
        if( $angle == 'true' ){ $x1--; $x2--; }
    }
}
```

I wrote this function to draw it using lines and a loop but its not coming up right like the red box.

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong? And can you even draw it like that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `imagepolygon()` or `imagefilledpolygon()` to draw non-rectangular shapes using GD. You may need to review a bit of trigonometry to figure out how to position the points to get right-angle corners.

Comment: +1, and the best part is when people ask why you're so frustrated you can say "Because I've been trying to draw a rectangle for 5 hours".  For me, it was triangles; based on certain parameters I had to draw a triangle which might be rotated to any angle, and was at a variable width, height and starting point.  Oh, and had to be transparent, so no default rotation for me.

Comment: Oh, and to the OP: just remember, when you're trying to find those points, from a mathematical perspective you're trying to calculate **several** triangles -- just remember, you only need to pass the first four coordinate pairs, the polygon functions will automatically draw the last connecting line segment for you.

Comment: you are right but i'm also creating some other complex graphics with the familiar quadrants. i did thought using imagepolygon() but can't use it. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Why can't you use `imagepolygon()`? What you're currently trying to do (overlapping a bunch of lines) definitely won't work reliably...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the built in [imagerotate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) along with a rectangle you've created with `imagefilledrectangle`.

Here's an example, creating a 20x100 red rectangle rotated 30 degrees:

```
$width = 20;
$height = 100;
$angle = 30;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

// Draw a red rectangle
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width, $height, $red);
// Rotate and fill out background with white
$im = imagerotate($im, $angle, $white);
```

Comment: no. can't rotate the complete image. because i'm also drawing some other complex shaps... rotating it will be :(.